# Oracle - only allow items to be inserted if three column values are unique and a fourth column is not equal to a given char

Tags: oracle

I am trying to enforce some uniqueness on data at the db level. For the sake of argument, my columns are:

```
ID
DocID (FK) 
FileName
FileRevision
Province
ActiveState
```

So in this example I want the combo of DocID, FIleName, and FileRevision entered only once. This is no issue, I can just create a UNIQUE constraint.

However the problem is, if 'ActiveState' is set to 'X', I want to allow any combo of those items.

In other words, only force uniqueness if ActiveState <> 'X'.

My understanding is I can not have a UNIQUE constraint with conditions. I've read about indexes, wondering if that's the path I need to travel?

I'm no Oracle expert (obviously), just looking for a tip!

Comment: you need a trigger

Comment: What if two rows for the same Doc/File/Revision exist, but one has ActiveState='X', and the other has ActiveState='Y'?

Comment: Hey there @MatBalie! Yeah, there can be any amount of dupes with an ActiveState <> X. The only time they need to be unique is if that is not the case.

Comment: That's the exact opposite of what you described in the OP. Attention to details matters in programming, especially getting <> and = mixed up.

Comment: `In other words, only force uniqueness if ActiveState <> 'X'.` in your question, and then your comment has the opposite `Yeah, there can be any amount of dupes with an ActiveState <> X.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use virtual columns and then create a unique constraint on the virtual columns:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  ID           NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  DocID        NUMBER,
  FileName     VARCHAR2(10),
  FileRevision NUMBER,
  Province     NUMBER,
  ActiveState  VARCHAR2(1),
  ActiveDocID  GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CASE ActiveState WHEN 'X' THEN NULL ELSE DocID END),
  ActiveFileName
               GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CASE ActiveState WHEN 'X' THEN NULL ELSE FileName END),
  ActiveFileRevision
               GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CASE ActiveState WHEN 'X' THEN NULL ELSE FileRevision END),
  CONSTRAINT table_name__uniq UNIQUE (
    ActiveDocID,
    ActiveFileName,
    ActiveFileRevision
  )
);
```

Comment: I believe that works with just one column being `NULL`? So, include the ActiveState column as a part of the Unique constraint, but with value `NULL` replacing `'X'`?

Answer (score 3):

For the same, Oracle provides the Conditoinal Index concept. You can create an conditional index on your table like below -

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_ActiveState
    ON YOUR_TABLE (CASE WHEN ActiveState = 'X' THEN NULL ELSE DocID END,
                   CASE WHEN ActiveState = 'X' THEN NULL ELSE FIleName END,
                   CASE WHEN ActiveState = 'X' THEN NULL ELSE FileRevision END);
```

Comment: I believe that works with just one column being `NULL`. So, include the ActiveState column as a part of the Unique constraint, but with values `NULL` instead of `'X'`?

Comment: @MatBailie you wouldn't include the ActiveState column in the unique index - the reason why this works is that indexes don't store entries where all the columns in the index are null.

Comment: @ankitbajpai the only thing I'd do differently with this answer is to swap the check around - currently, if `activestate` is null, the index wouldn't store a row. That's ok if `activestate` is not nullable, but otherwise it doesn't match the OP's logic (now it doesn't enforce uniqueness if `activestate` is X or null). I'd change the checks to `WHEN activestate = 'X' THEN NULL ELSE ... END`

Comment: @Boneist, Agreed and updated the answer.